# Apache dispatcher rules not rejecting /.json;%0aa.css

Tags: apache, aem, dispatcher

I am unable to block/reject `/.json;%0aa.css`

The error I get in dispatcher error.log is

```
The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: Cannot map GET /.json;%0aa.css
```

Although I am able to block `/.json` as I dont get any error for this.

I used `;%0aa.css` with other URLs but they went ahead without any issue.

So my question is how can I block/reject `/.json;%0aa.css` as it is printing some output on browser.

Comment: Did you try a wildcard like `.json*`?

Comment: yes I did. But the issue is for this URL it seems the request is not matched against the Rules because of the error.